I'm trying to make an API request from my react native app. In isolation, the api works with the correct authToken but doesn't in my react-native app
Whenever I run it on my web browser, I get an error that says "Uncaught error. Failed to fetch" Here's the code that causes the problem.
    useEffect(() => {
      const fetchTweets = async() => {
      const url = 'http://localhost:3000/tweet';
      const authToken =
        'eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJ0b2tlbklkIjozNX0.PhYEPigRB0Jpj6uW11-J8roshWrR4rfdfCPiXgS2gig'
      const res = await fetch(url, {
        headers: {
          Authorization: `Bearer ${authToken}`
        },
      })
      if (res.status !== 200){
        console.log('Error fetching the api')
      }
      const data = await res.json()
      console.log(data);
      setTweets(data)
    };

    fetchTweets();
  }, []);

I've ensured that the server is running and have even tested that it works with the ThunderClient vsCode extension. Please help.
I went to chatGPT, copilot, youtube... I even initialized CORS in the backend I built but still nothing. I copied notJust.dev youtube's video on a twitter frontend integrated with the backend. He never got this error but now I do and I can't resolve it no matter what I try. I even cloned his repo word for word and it still doesn't work.

You might have ensured stuff, but that doesn't mean you can just leave all those details and code out. They are relevant. I'm not going to just take your word that all the things you havn't shown are correct.

const url = 'http://localhost:3000/tweet';
will not work in react native as it will refer to the phone not the local machine.
So you have to use the ip address instead. Something like below
http://192.168.43.87:3000/tweet
